# Solving for variable exponent also used outside exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math is rusty. Looking for a pointer to rule/identity to help me isolate $n$ in $An = B^n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to go about it, one numerical, one algebraic.

---

The first of these is numerical, and may be calculated as follows:

$$An=B^n\implies\begin{cases}n=(B^n)/A&;n<1\\n=\log_B(An)&;n>1\end{cases}$$

$\tiny\text{Note the trivial case of $n=1$, which would give $n=1$ trivially.}$

One can determine which range the solution will fall in rather easily, either with a calculator or not.

---

The first case is $n<1:$

$$\begin{align}n_0&=1\\n_1&=(B^1)/A=B/A\\n_2&=(B^{n_1})/A\\n_3&=(B^{n_2})/A\\\vdots\ \\n&=\lim_{k\to\infty}n_k\end{align}$$

A similar case for $n>1:$

$$\begin{align}n_0&=1\\n_1&=\log_B(A)\\n_2&=\log_B(An_1)\\n_3&=\log_b(An_2)\\\vdots\ \\n&=\lim_{k\to\infty}n_k\end{align}$$

This method is known as fixed point iteration and is basically an infinite substitution of sorts.  There are other similar methods known as 'numerical methods' that let you get as close to the solution you want.  For example :

$$n_{k+1}=n_k-\cfrac{B^{n_k}-An_k}{\ln(B)B^{n_k}-A}$$

also works, but it is no longer as algebraic as fixed point iteration.

---

The second method is to use the Lambert W function :

$$An=B^n=e^{\ln(B)n}$$

$$Ane^{-\ln(B)n}=1$$

$$-\ln(B)ne^{-\ln(B)n}=\frac{\ln(B)}{-A}$$

$$-\ln(B)n=W\left(\frac{\ln(B)}{-A}\right)$$

> $$n=\cfrac{W\left(\frac{\ln(B)}{-A}\right)}{-\ln(B)}$$

However, you could argue that the Lambert W function is calculated using numerical methods (like above), so whether or not this qualifies as a solution depends on what you call a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.